# Mongodb to return array within the nested object

Tags: mongodb, pymongo

How would i go about picking the array within the nested object as shown in the below image:

[image]

I can pick up section_information as below.

```
cur = collection.find_one({"filename":"172977114"}, {"section_information": 1})
```

But I am not sure or unable to fetch **row_cells** from each object (0_0,1_0...) from **section_information**.

Answer (score 0):

`find_one()` returns a dictionary, in which `section_information` is a list, so you can iterate that list, then traverse the dictionary items to get the values you need.

```
for section_information in cur.get('section_information', {}):
    for k, v in section_information.items():
        print(v.get('row_cells'))
```

Comment: Yes, I am doing that. But I was wondering if there is a way to directly extract few fields from nested object.